# unclear index error python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

This is my third thread in StackOverflow.
I think I already learnt a LOT by reading threads here and clearing my doubts.

I'm trying to transform an excel table, in my own python script. I've done so much, and now that I'm almost finishing the script, I'm getting an Err message that I can't really understand. Here is my code: (I tried to give as much information as possible!)

```
def _sensitivity_analysis(datasource):
    #datasource is a list with data that may be used for HBV_model() function;
    datasource_length = len(datasource) #returns tha size of the data time series
    sense_param = parameter_vector #collects the parameter data from the global vector (parameter_vector);
    sense_index = np.linspace(0, 11, 12) #Vector that reflects the indexes of parameters that must be analyzed (0 - 11)
    sense_factor = np.linspace(0.5, 2, 31) #Vecor with the variance factors that multiply the original parameter value;
    ns_sense = [] #list that will be filled with Nasch-Sutcliff values (those numbers will be data for sensitivity analysis)
    for i in range(sense_factor.shape[0]): #start column loop
        ns_sense.append([]) #create column in ns_sense matrix
        for j in range(sense_index.shape[0]): #start row loop
            aux = sense_factor[i]*sense_param[j] #Multiplies the param[j] value by the factor[i] value
            print(i,j,aux) #debug purposes
            sense_param[j] = aux #substitutes the original parameter value by the modified one
            hbv = _HBV_model(datasource, sense_param) #run the model calculations (works awesomely!)
            sqrdiff = _square_diff() #does square-difference calculations for Nasch-Sutcliff;
            average = _qcalc_qmed() #does square-difference calculations for Nasch-Sutcliff [2];
            nasch = _nasch_sutcliff(sqrdiff, average) #Returns the Nasch-Sutcliff calculation value
            ns_sense[i].insert(j, nasch) #insert the value into ns_sense(i, j) for further uses;
            sense_param = np.array([np.float64(catchment_area), np.float64(thresh_temp), 
                             np.float64(degreeday_factor), np.float64(field_capacity), 
                                       np.float64(shape_coeficient), np.float64(model_paramC), 
                                       np.float64(surfaceflow_param), np.float64(thresh_surface_level), 
                                       np.float64(interflow_param), np.float64(baseflow_param), 
                                       np.float64(percolation_param), np.float64(soilmoist_param)]) #restores sense_param to original values
            for i in range(len(datasource)): #HBV_model() transforms original data (index = 5) in a fully calculated data (index 17)
                for j in range(12): #in order to return it to original state before a new loop
                    datasource[i].pop() #data is popped out;
    print(ns_sense) #debug purposes
```

So, when I run _sensitivity_analysis(datasource) I receive this message:

```
 File "<ipython-input-47-c9748eaba818>", line 4, in <module>
    aux = sense_factor[i]*sense_param[j]
IndexError: index 3652 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 31;
```

I'm totally aware that it is talking about a index that is not accessible as it does not exists.

Explaining my situation, datasource is a list with index [3652]. But I can't see how the console is trying to access index 3652, as I'm not asking it to do so. The only point I'm trying to access such value is in the final loop:

```
for i in range(len(datasource)):
```

I'm really lost. I'd really apreciate if you could help me guys! If you need more info, I can give you.

Comment: Put the line `print(i, j)` before the line that's getting the error. What does it print?

Comment: From the definition of sense_factor, number of samples expected is 31 but you are looping through the whole 3652 indexes, the error started happening at the 32nd loop. You only seeing the 3652 because that is the last index. sense_factor evenly 31 samples space and calling the index 3562 is outside the range. sense_factor has only 31 samples (evenly spaced), whereas the loop goes 3652 times.

Comment: Yeah deaspo! I changed the i and j in the final loops for k and l. Now things are getting clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess: `sense_factor = np.linspace(0.5, 2, 31)` has 31 elements - you ask for element 3652 and it naturally blows. `i` takes this value in final loop. Rewrite final loop as:

```
        for k in range(len(datasource))
            for m in range(12):
                datasource[k].pop()
```

However your code has many issues - you should have been not using indexes 
*at all* - instead use for loops directly on the arrays

Comment: Mr_and_Mrs_D I'm sure I can get a lot better if I keep practicing coding. I'm really newbie coding stuff hahahaha! I thank you very much for the support!

Comment: What does the call `datasource[j].pop()` do @Ramon ?

Comment: It's a uneffective way to "clean" the datasource. What I mean is that when HBV_model() runs, it appends many data to the original "datasource". As I want to run the HBV_model() x-times in loop, I need the original datasource again for it not crash.

Comment: Then you should probably drop these two last loops and just pass a copy to `hbv = _HBV_model(np.copy(datasource), sense_param)` - no ? What is the shape of `datasource` ?

Comment: If you wanted to pop last twelve elements the correct way would be `for i in range(len(datasource)): datasource[i][:] = datasource[i][:-12] # exclude last 12 elements` - although if datasource were a numpy matrix you could use numpy indexing

Comment: In other words if `datasource = np.zeros((6, 17), dtype=np.float64)` then `datasource[:, :-12]` has all 12 last element chopped off from each column, and you avoid the copy - but you must edit `_HBV_model` to woirk with numpy arrays and not list of lists (that datasource is probably)

Comment: Wow! That worked perfectly! I'm such a newbie hahahaahaha! I'm getting more used to the numpy now. Actually this is the first time I'm coding using numpy. I was practicing creating little games such as tic tac toe and stuff. Now I'm working with numbers, I've read that numpy could give me better resolution for calculation. Datasource is a list of lists as I'm used to work, but I'm about to read more about numpy documentation. Thank you sooo much Mr_and_Mrs_D!

Comment: Please start accepting and or upvoting if the answers here helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You reused your variable names, here:

```
for i in range(sense_factor.shape[0]):
    ...
    for j in range(sense_index.shape[0]):
```

and then here:

```
for i in range(len(datasource)):
    for j in range(12):
```

so in `aux = sense_factor[i]*sense_param[j]`, you're using the wrong value of `i`, and it's basically a fluke that you're not using the wrong value of `j` too.

Don't reuse variable names in the same scope.

Comment: Aww man! I feel really dumb for this mistake! hahahaa! Thank you for your time user2357112!